# SOLR query coming from my application is not parsed the same as when i do it from SOLR admin console

Tags: parsing, solr, lucene

I am fairly new to Solr/Lucene and am not a developer. I am troubleshooting issues where my queries that use AND/NOT are not returning the results as they should. When i run the search using them it seems to only treat the 1st word before the AND/NOT. I think i know why. see below

I have tried several ways to no avail.

Catalina log show the following when i run from our .net application

```
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={spellcheck=true&start=0&q=content_en:"GINGER+NOT+BRAD"&?=&rows=1000} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
```

It appears to be putting my query in just one q=content_en: with the NOT included

Catalina log show the following when i run from solr admin

```
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params={start=0&version=2.2&q=content_en:ginger++NOT+content_en:brad&indent=on&rows=10} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1
```

It is properly treating each criteria by segregating them.

I have tried EVERY single combination from my application front end and still no go.

I'm sure you gurus will see this and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: I see `"GINGER+NOT+BRAD"&?=` and the `?=` seems like a syntax error (as far as an URL parser is concerned). Please check if your URL escaping is watertight.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post your .net code that you are using, so we can understand what you are doing with the code and why it is different.

In my case, I use SolrNet but I never see any difference unless I use an API to treat the query as different.

Comment: I agree, we need to see how your application is constructing the query to send to Solr to figure out your issue.